# R markdown: reduce space between text and image

Tags: r, r-markdown

In R markdown (output: html document), I want to insert an image between paragraphs (no text wrap).
But when rendering I'm getting too large space between the paragraph and the image.
I'm using the following code for that.

````
### Text 1
            
some more text.....
            
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='top'}
library(cowplot)
ggdraw() + 
   draw_image("dog.png", width = 0.5)
```
### Text 2
        
some more text...
````

This is how the output looks like, but as I marked in red, I want to reduce the space between the image and text.
[image]
How can I reduce/change space between them? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the markdown syntax for inserting image.

```
### Text 1
            
some more text.....
            
![](dog.png)

### Text 2
        
some more text..
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is the space inserted in case of using draw_image() function?

Comment: @r.carnahan, my guess is, `draw_image` uses functions from `{magick}` package, which is taking this much space to draw the image again